# Digito o xpath correto de um botão, mas o selenium diz que o xpath não existe

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou fazendo um bot em python usando selenium e preciso clicar no botão de curtir do instagram usando código.

Para localizar o botão de curtir estou usando o método `find_element_by_xpath()`.

Para eu ter certeza, cliquei em inspecionar elemento no Chrome e cliquei em "Copy XPath", já que o xpath desse botão nunca muda. Mas quando vou rodar o código, ele dá o seguinte erro:

> `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

O código está assim:

```py
like_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button')
like_button.click()
```

Mas por algum motivo não funciona

Comment: Tu já deu um sleep() antes do `find_element_by_xpath`? Só para garantir que a página tenha carregado.

Comment: sim, já cheguei até a daar um sleep de 20 segundos, mas mesmo assim ele fala que não existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa mensagem esta dizendo que o elemento não esta na DOM quando você procurou por ele, seria prudente esperar ele estar ~disponivel~ na tela durante algum tempo.

Primeiramente, dei uma folhada no instagram e parece que seu xpath ta errado, mude seu xpath pra:

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button
```

Segundo, não aconselho você a usar o caminho dessa forma, qualquer mudança vai causar problemas no seu script, que tal elaborar ele um pouco mais? Por exemplo ir pro elemento 'curtir' baseado em algum texto que você esta procurando? Segue um xpath que vai retornar o curtir baseado no nome do perfil, no caso SPENCER_MELO:

```
//a[text()='SPENCER_MELO']/ancestor::article//span[@aria-label='Like']
```

Sobre esperar antes de clicar, segue como fazer abaixo.

Imports necessarios nesse exemplo:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Uso:

```py
# Da pra trocar por xpath se quiser.
like_css = '#react-root span[aria-label=\'Like\']'

element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS, like_css)))
element.click()
```

Comment: Spencer Melo, eu tentei e deu um erro:  
File "C:\Users\luisg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

achei estranho pq dps de Message:  <br>não apareceu nada. Sabe me ajudar?

Comment: Esse elemento que você esta procurando não esta disponivel na DOM ou ele esta dentro de um iframe, procure no html se tem algum "iframe", outra coisa, edita sua pergunta com o html do botao, fica mais facil pra gente responder.

Comment: desculpe, não entendi o que você quis dizer com o html do botão. Só o elemento button?
De qualquer forma, é o botão de like do insta, todos eles têm os mesmos valores com os mesmos atributos, é só dar uma olhada lá pq eu realmente não entendi o que quer dizer o html do botão :/

Comment: Bom, voce gerou esse xpath  aqui `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button` olhando (inspecionar) o html do botao no navegador, seria bom se voce colocasse o codigo html na pergunta, assim podemos ver como ta a estrutura do html.

Comment: @LuisMeirelles dei uma editada importante na resposta, ve se ela consegue, finalmente, responder sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como esta essa estrutura do `html`, porem acredito que se você mudar o loca do `click()` fazer até o `span` em vez do `button`.

```
like_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]')

like_button.click()
```

deva corrigir esse problema